# Como implementar exclusão no Junit com Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Preciso saber como implementar a exclusão de registro através do Junit(Testes Unitários) com Spring Boot, estou tendo dificuldade, a inclusão está funcionando como podem ver abaixo;

```
@Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PessoaService pessoaService;

    @Test
    public void testAdicionarPessoa() throws Exception {
        Pessoa pessoa1 = new Pessoa("Douglas", "399.536.640-64");
        this.pessoaService.salvar(pessoa1);
        // Assertions.assertThat(pessoa1.getName()).isNotNull();
    }
```

Eu tentei deletar o registro dessa forma, porém não tive sucesso.

```
@Test
    public void testeDeletePessoa() throws Exception {
        Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa();
        this.pessoaRepository.delete((long) 4);

    }
```

**Aceito sugestões e estou aberto a perguntas**

Ao tentar inserir o código gerou esse erro;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, apareceu alguma mensagem de erro, se sim, informe o erro,  que facilita encontrarmos a solução.

Comment: Oi, tudo bom? acabei de atualizar minha postagem, poderia por favor da uma olhada?

Comment: Você está usando que banco de dados ?

Comment: estou sim, é o banco de dados Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

O erro está dando porque ele não está encontrando no banco de dados um registro com um id 4 para exclusão.

Provavelmente você já executou o teste uma vez e acabou excluido o registro.

Uma solução para esse tipo de problema é a utilização de banco de dados que são executados em memória para teste, ou seja, o banco só tem funciona enquanto a aplicação está em execução, por exemplo o H2 ou o HSQLDB.

Segue alguns links complementares:

https://cezbatistao.wordpress.com/2016/05/05/comecando-com-o-spring-boot-parte-2/

https://medium.com/@josevieiraneto/tdd-com-spring-boot-b5bf7ec725e